# XPath Select All Attribute Name Value Pairs from Entire XML Document

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XPath and XML. I was wondering if there is an XPath expression to select all the attribute names and their respective values from an entire XML document.

**As a simpler example to what I have:**

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
            <money currency="Dollars"></money>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
            <money currency="Dollars"></money>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
            <money currency="Euros"></money>
    </book>
        <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
            <money currency="Dollars"></money>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

**I want this:**

```
category : COOKING
lang : en
currency : Dollars

category : CHILDREN
lang : en
currency : Dollars

category : WEB
lang : en
currency : Euros

category : WEB
lang : en
currency : Dollars
```

The thing is I want this expression to work for any XML document. Any other suggestions as to how I can do this are welcome as well. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible.. Please provide an example input and the expected output.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the value of an attribute is not a node and cannot be selected by an XPath expression. But it is certainly possible to output a list of name/value pairs using XSLT. Show us (at least) the expected output.

Comment: I provided a simpler example. My document is to large to share but the goal is the same. Thank you.

Comment: "*I want this expression to work for any XML document*" In your example, there is a clear grouping by book. That cannot work for **any** document - XML is far more *extensible* than that.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: +1 for your helpful explanations. However, just because something is not a node doesn't mean it can't be "selected" (in some sense) by an XPath expression. E.g. `string(/*/book[1]/@category)` I'm sure you know this, but the way you phrased it might give the unaware a mistaken impression.

Comment: @LarsH What you show does not select, it converts - and it converts multiple nodes into a single string. But it's true that **in XPath 2.0** you could do `select="//@*/string()"` to select the string values (plural), so I stand corrected on that point.

Comment: @michael.hor257k. Will "//@*/string()" give me all the values of the attributes except their names? Thank you.

Comment: @pseudorandom Yes, if you're using a processor that supports XPath 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: That's why I said "in some sense." I don't see how `//@*/string()` selects any more, or converts any less, than `string(/*/book[1]/@category)`. As for converting multiple nodes into a single string, I don't see what you mean. `/*/book[1]/@category` can only select one node; and even if it selected more than one, `string()` would convert the first, rather than multiple nodes into a single string.

Comment: @LarsH I am thinking of this in the context of the question above, where the intent is to select the values of **all** attributes. In this context, any expression selecting a single attribute is irrelevant. OTOH, when dealing with multiple attributes, there is a big difference between `string(//*@)` and `//@*/string()`. The latter is useful (again, in XPath 2.0 only), because it selects the values of **all** attributes - which **is** much more than `string(/*/book[1]/@category)`.  The former is not (in fact, it generates an error).

Comment: The purpose of the expression I gave selecting a single attribute was not to answer the question, but to give an example illustrating a point about XPath. The expression `string(//@*)` gives an error only in XPath 2.0 (and above); but in no version does `string(...)` convert multiple nodes into a single string.

Comment: "*illustrating a point about XPath.*" I am not sure what your point is at this point. I already conceded that string-values of attributes *can* be selected. They just cannot be selected the way you show - and cannot be selected at all in XSLT 1.0. "*in no version does string(...) convert multiple nodes into a single string.*" In XPath 1.0, the string() function converts a node-set to a string by returning the value of the first node.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your input (after you fix the mismatching tags `<money>` and `</currency>`!) and other reasonably similar XML documents - but it cannot be guaranteed to work with **any** XML document:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', ., '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

OTOH, this *will* work with any XML - but the output will be just a single list of all attribute name/value pairs in the entire document, with no separation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', ., '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
category: COOKING
lang: en
currency: Dollars
category: CHILDREN
lang: en
currency: Dollars
category: WEB
lang: en
currency: Euros
category: WEB
lang: en
currency: Dollars
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the mismatch.

Comment: I have never used XLST before. How do you run it? Thank you very much. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: @pseudorandom This has nothing to do with the above question. I suggest you post a new one (although I suspect it will be considered off-topic for Stack Overflow).